# Using jQuery function if element width is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

I'm new to jQuery and I found this code to use in my site:

```
$(function() {
  elemWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#checkVw"), null).width, 10);
  halfWidth = parseInt(window.innerWidth / 2, 10);
  alert("Your browser " + ((elemWidth == halfWidth) ? "" : "does not ") + "support VW and VH");
});
```

The code check if my element have the size that I define in css, returning if users browser support my size unit (viewport).

What I need is load a script if *elemWidth* value is not the same as *halfWidth*, but I don't know how to change this alert to a conditioning function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `((elemWidth == halfWidth) ? "" : "does not "` makes use of the [conditional ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

It is short for:

```
if (elemWidth == halfWidth) {
  // ""
} else {
  // "does not"
}
```

Therefore if you want to load a script if the `elemWidth` value is not the same as `halfWidth`, then you could simply use the [`$.getScript` function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) or whatever you are using the load the script.

```
if (elemWidth !== halfWidth) {
  $.getScript('...');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straight forward, place the comparison of the two values in a condition, and lot a script if they are not equal.

```
$(function () {
    var elemWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#checkVw"), null).width, 10);
    var halfWidth = parseInt(window.innerWidth / 2, 10);

    if ( elemWidth !== halfWidth ) {

        $.getScript('whatever.js');

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elemWidth =    parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#checkVw"), null).width, 10);
var halfWidth = parseInt(window.innerWidth / 2, 10);
elementWidth !== halfWidth ? alert("Your browser " + ((elemWidth == halfWidth) ? "" : "does not ") + "support VW and VH");
```